# Saving the posted data from four random rows so they don't randomize after page generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm using the code:

```
<h2>
<% random_bullets = Bullet.all %>
<ul>
  <% random_bullets.shuffle.first(4).each do |r| %>
<br>
    <li><%= db.save(r.content) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
</h2>
```

to pull four random bullets from my db and post them to a page; what I'm trying to do is get them to save the bullets so they're only randomized after the page is generated. Is there anything I can do to this code to achieve this? If not, what can I do to achieve this. The code is in embedded Ruby and the db is a sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting random bullets and randomising belongs in your controller. Once there I recommend setting a cookie which contains an array of bullet.ids in order.
Then you can just iterate over the array if it exists else create a new one and save it.

In your controller:

```
if cookies[:bullets].nil?
  @bullets = Bullet.all.shuffle.first(4)
  cookies[:bullets] = @bullets.collect(&:id)
else
  @bullets = []
  cookies[:bullets].each do |id|
    @bullets << Bullet.find(id)
  end
end
```

in your view:

```
<ul>
  <% @bullets.each do |r| %>
    <li><%= r.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Are you aware that it's invalid html to put a `<ul>` within a `<h2>` or to put a `<br>` within a `<ul>`?

Comment: I used that code outside the controller and it worked just fine.

Comment: That's all I'm trying to do right now is get it to work in a view. Do you know how I can do so?

Comment: I was not aware of this. I'm still a major newbie.

Comment: I received an "undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass" on the view.

Comment: No. Cookies is a reference to storing a cookie on the client machine... Hopefully you know what that means. So no db column. The code is valid, so you must have misnamed @bullets someewhere.

Comment: I copy/pasted. And yes I do know what that means.